# General term of a recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, power-series

While studying the Frobenius method, my book ended up deriving the following recurrence relation

$$ a_{k+2} = \frac{-1}{(k+1)(k+2)}a_k  $$

The book then derived the following inital conditions,
$a_0=\alpha$ and $a_1=\beta$

and concluded that the following relations hold
$$ a_{2k}= \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}\alpha $$

$$ a_{2k+1}= \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}\beta $$

While it seems intuitively obvious, I'm having troubles proving it, so I'd like to get some help.

I tought about proving it inductively, but I'm stuck at the induction step.

I'd also like to get some information about proving in general what the general term of a recurrence relation is.

Thank you

Comment: Please remove the **[ordinary-differential-equations]** tag, @JackV, since this question has got nothing to do with [ordinary differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation).

Comment: hint: $a_{k+2} = \frac{-1}{(k+2)(k+1)}a_k \iff (k+2)!a_{k+2} = - k!a_k$

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use induction for the even case, the odd case is similar.

We have for the case $k=1$

$$a_{2}=-\frac{1}{2\cdot1} a_0=\frac{(-1)^{1}}{2!}\alpha$$

Assume it holds for $k=n$, then we have for $k=n+1$

$$a_{2(n+1)}=a_{2n+2}=\frac{-1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}a_{2n}\overbrace{=}^{IH}-\frac{1}{(2k+1)(2k+2)}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}\alpha $$
$$=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n+2)!}\alpha=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2(n+1))!}\alpha$$

so it also holds for $k=n+1$, which completes the inductive step.

See [1](http://discrete.openmathbooks.org/dmoi2/sec_recurrence.html) and [2](https://www.math.hkust.edu.hk/%7Emabfchen/Math2343/Recurrence.pdf) for examples.